# CircuiTikz undashed current arrow on a dashed line

Tags: circuitikz

I wish to add a current label on a dashed line, using a current arrow. But when I do this, the borders of my arrows are also dahsed and it really looks bad.

Here is my code :

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V={\small $V_{CC}$}] (0,2) to (5,2) to[R, l={\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{{\small $Charge$}}}] (5,0) to (0,0); 
    \draw[color=red, thick] (3,2) to[short, *-] (2.75,0.75) to (3.25, 1.25) to[short, -*] (3,0);
    \draw[color=red, thick, dashed] (0.1,1.9) to[short, i={\small $i_{d\acute efaut}$}] (2.65,1.9) to (2.65,0.1) to (0.1,0.1) to (0.1,1.9);
\end{circuitikz}
```

And what it looks like :
[image: Image of a short-circuit error on a DC circuit with a visual issue on the short-circuit current arrow]

And I'd like it to look like this :
[image: Image of a short-circuit error on a DC circuit with no more issue]

I don't really know what to try to make it look as I'd like. I already tried to add `solid`, `dash=solid` or `dash pattern=on` to the `short` object but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I'll think of it if I have others questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you got bitten by the fact that the `dash` is inherited down by the drawing routine that draws the `currarrow` node. Changing the dash mode to the `short` element does not work (the dashing is global to the path, you can look at the discussion in the FAQ in the manual).

You have two solutions:

1. (if you want this just for one current arrow): use `advanced currents and voltages` (section 5.6 for now) for this one;
2. (if you like to make all the current arrows undashed), you can use the component hook for `currarrow` (look in the manual at section 9.3.1), which I suppose is what you want:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\ctikz@hook@start@draw@component@currarrow}{\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V={\small $V_{CC}$}] (0,2) -- (5,2)
    to[R, l={\small\textit{Charge}}, label/align=rotate] (5,0)
        -- (0,0);
    \draw[color=red, thick] (3,2) to[short, *-] (2.75,0.75)
        -- (3.25, 1.25) to[short, -*] (3,0);
    \draw[color=red, thick, dashed] (0.1,1.9) 
        to[short, i={\small $i_{\textit{défaut}}$}] (2.65,1.9)
        -- (2.65,0.1) -- (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,1.9);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also took the liberty to change the plain `to` to just lines, and to re-write the labels in what I think is more correct (don't use math mode for just italic text: look carefully at the spacing around *f* in *défaut*!).

By the way, if you find yourself to add `\small` for all the labels, voltage, etc., you can define your own style (see section 5.6):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\ctikz@hook@start@draw@component@currarrow}{\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\ctikzset{bipole label style/.style={font=\small}}
\ctikzset{bipole annotation style/.style={font=\small}}
\ctikzset{bipole voltage style/.style={font=\small}}
\ctikzset{bipole current style/.style={font=\small}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V=$V_{CC}$] (0,2) -- (5,2)
    to[R, l={\textit{Charge}}, label/align=rotate] (5,0)
        -- (0,0);
    \draw[color=red, thick] (3,2) to[short, *-] (2.75,0.75)
        -- (3.25, 1.25) to[short, -*] (3,0);
    \draw[color=red, thick, dashed] (0.1,1.9)
    to[short, i=$i_{\textit{défaut}}$] (2.65,1.9)
        -- (2.65,0.1) -- (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,1.9);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for setting `défaut` in text mode - the spaces around the f nearly made me cry :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I noticed that too! Once you see it, you *can't* unsee it... On the topic of this question, though, I am wondering if the hook should be the default behavior...

Comment: That's one of the biggest risks of using latex - one now sees such things :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped me.